# htaccess problem

Tags: apache, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /home
RewriteRule ^()$ index.php [NC,L]
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/?.*\..*$) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ $1.php [NC]
```

I get a css problem (blank) when I visit http://dot.com/home/index.php/

Answer (score 0):

Turning on the logging can help. Just add these directives to the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteLog "/foo/bar.log" 
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

Make sure to turn them off when done, as they can slow down your server.